# How to resolve React Warning: Invalid argument supplied to oneOfType. Expected an array of check functions, but received undefined at index 2.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I locate the `Expected an array of check functions, but received undefined`

Can it be missing prop type definition?

How do I navigate in the list below? Note that most link to me code are on `export class ...` declarations.

Thanks

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied to oneOfType. Expected an array of check functions, but received undefined at index 2.

console.<computed>                          @   index.js:1
printWarning                                @   warning.js:33
warning                                     @   warning.js:57
createUnionTypeChecker                      @   factoryWithTypeCheckers.js:326
./node_modules/react-table/es/propTypes.js  @   propTypes.js:85
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
fn                                          @   bootstrap:150
./node_modules/react-table/es/index.js      @   defaultProps.js:9
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
fn                                          @   bootstrap:150
./src/views/TableList/TerminologyTable.jsx  @   ProductRow.jsx:4
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
fn                                          @   bootstrap:150
./src/routes/app.jsx                        @   app.jsx:1
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
fn                                          @   bootstrap:150
./src/components/Header/HeaderLinks.jsx     @   Header.jsx:8
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
fn                                          @   bootstrap:150
./src/components/Header/Header.jsx          @   GraphCard.jsx:53
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
fn                                          @   bootstrap:150
./src/containers/App/App.jsx                @   UserCard.jsx:35
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
fn                                          @   bootstrap:150
./src/index.js                              @   spinner.gif:1
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
fn                                          @   bootstrap:150
1                                           @   UserProfile.jsx:16
__webpack_require__                         @   bootstrap:785
checkDeferredModules                        @   bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback                        @   bootstrap:32
(anonymous)                                 @   main.chunk.js:1
```

EDIT ============

Below is a sample code refers to `@   UserProfile.jsx:16`  at the end of the list above.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Grid, Row, Col,
    FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl
} from 'react-bootstrap';

import {Card} from 'components/Card/Card.jsx';
import {FormInputs} from 'components/FormInputs/FormInputs.jsx';
import {UserCard} from 'components/UserCard/UserCard.jsx';
import Button from 'elements/CustomButton/CustomButton.jsx';
import { ProjectName, ProjectSlogan } from 'variables/Config';

// 
// 

/* line 16 */ export class UserProfile extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        // console.log("userprofile", this.props)
        const {mbouser} = this.props

        return (
            <div className="content">xxxxxxx

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: show us you're code, you should know that by now.

Comment: I was hoping to get instructions where to look... and save the lengthy code.

Comment: and the error is clear, you've supplied invalid prop type.

Comment: Added code after removing most of the code - still getting the warning

Comment: the error might be in  react table

Comment: check your prop types definition, If not, it could be coming from third party libraries.

Comment: you're not showing the part of the code that uses PropTypes.oneOfType . find-in-files that string and paste it . Probably one (at index 2) of the entries has a typo, for exmple :

someProp: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string, PropTypes.obje])

Comment: @JuniusL. Remove react-table completely - no change, but good excuse to remove react-table v6... Thanks!

Comment: @JuniusL. Update. Removing react-table v6 solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing react-table v6 solved the problem.

As suggested by @JuniusL. above.

I publish this "answer" in hope that it will help others.
Thanks.

Comment: I solved the problem by going from react-table version 6.11.5 to 7.6.3.
Actually I ran `npm install`, so, I updated everything, so it could have been another package that gave the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just changed these

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function useGetAdvertising({
    option = PropTypes.string = ""
}) {
...
}
```

to

```
export default function useGetAdvertising({
    option = ""
}) {
...
}

useGetAdvertising.propTypes = {
    option: PropTypes.string,
};

useGetAdvertising.defaultProps = {
    option: "",
}
```